# How to parallelize processing of partially ordered messages?

Tags: netty, netty4

My Netty based app

1. ingests hundreds of thousands of messages per second from a single TCP connection
2. processes those messages in a couple of inbound handlers
3. sends processing results somewhere downstream

Currently, all this is running on thread, as it is on a single TCP connection. I would like to know how I can parallelize 2. The difficulty is that messages cannot just be processed in parallel nilly-willy, because there is a partial order of messages. You can think of this as there being a `key(message)` function, and all messages for which this function returns the same result need to processed sequentially, but if the results are different, they may run in parallel. So I am thinking of having a mapping from message to thread like `hash(key(message)) % threadCount`.

Imagine this pipeline:

```java
pipeline.addLast(deframer);
pipeline.addLast(new IdleStateHandler(...));
pipeline.addLast(decoder);
pipeline.addLast(bizLogicHandler1);
pipeline.addLast(bizLogicHandler2);
```

In the decoder, I am able to compute the result of `key(message)`, so I would like to parallelize everything downstream of decoder. It is [documented](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelPipeline.html) that in order to use multiple threads I can do

```
static final EventExecutorGroup group = new DefaultEventExecutorGroup(16);
...
pipeline.addLast(group, "bizLogicHandler1", bizLogicHandler1);
pipeline.addLast("bizLogicHandler2", bizLogicHandler2);
```

which I guess means bizLogicHandler1 and everything below it (in the above example that would be bizLogicHandler2) will be able to run in parallel? (Or would I have to specify `group` for bizLogicHandler2 as well?)

The above will however still run completely serial, as the documentation explains, offering `UnorderedThreadPoolEventExecutor` as an alternative to maximize parallelism, at the cost of getting rid of ordering completely, which does not work in my case.

Looking at the interfaces `EventExecutorGroup` and `EventExecutor`, I don't see how it would be possible to convey which messages can be processed in parallel, and which must be processed sequentially.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out this is quite easy to do with one [LocalServerChannel](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/local/LocalServerChannel.html) and as many [LocalChannel](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/local/LocalChannel.html)s as parallelism desired.

The server channel will receive messages and dispatch them to one of the client channels. The other direction (from client channels to the server channel) works as well. I successfully parallelized an app this way to allow for much higher throughput, scaling out to more cores.

Here's a bare bones version, with most of the error handling, logging, and business logic stripped away:

```java
public class Parallelizer extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<Message> {

    private static final AtomicInteger EPHEMERAL_PORT = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private final Channel[] internalChannels;
    private final AtomicReference<ChannelHandlerContext> upstreamCtx = new AtomicReference<>(null);

    public Parallelizer(EventLoopGroup eventLoopGroup, List<ChannelInitializer<Channel>> channelInitializers) throws InterruptedException {
        internalChannels = (Channel[]) Array.newInstance(Channel.class, channelInitializers.size());

        int port = EPHEMERAL_PORT.getAndIncrement();
        final LocalAddress addr = new LocalAddress("PARALLELIZER-" + port);
        createServerChannel(eventLoopGroup, addr);

        channelInitializers.forEach(channelChannelInitializer -> createClientChannel(eventLoopGroup, addr, channelChannelInitializer));

        waitForInternalClientsToConnect();
    }

    private void waitForInternalClientsToConnect() throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (internalChannels) {
            while (internalChannels[internalChannels.length - 1] == null) {
                internalChannels.wait();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
        ctx.close();
    }

    private void dispatch(Message msg, int clientChannelIdx) {
        Channel channel = internalChannels[clientChannelIdx];
        channel.writeAndFlush(msg, channel.voidPromise());
    }

    private void createClientChannel(EventLoopGroup eventLoopGroup, LocalAddress addr, ChannelInitializer<Channel> channelInitializer) {
        Bootstrap cb = new Bootstrap();
        cb.group(eventLoopGroup)
                .channel(LocalChannel.class)
                .handler(channelInitializer);
        cb.connect(addr);
    }

    private void createServerChannel(EventLoopGroup eventLoopGroup, LocalAddress addr) throws InterruptedException {
        ServerBootstrap sb = new ServerBootstrap();
        sb.group(eventLoopGroup)
                .channel(LocalServerChannel.class)
                .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<LocalChannel>() {
                    @Override
                    public void initChannel(LocalChannel ch) {
                        ch.pipeline().addLast(new InternalHandler());
                    }
                });
        sb.bind(addr).sync();
    }

    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Message msg) {
        final int hash = msg.getDistributionKey().hashCode();
        int clientChannelIdx = Integer.remainderUnsigned(hash, internalChannels.length);
        dispatch(msg, clientChannelIdx);
    }

    private class InternalHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<ByteBuf> {
        @Override
        public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
            ctx.close();
        }

        @Override
        public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
            synchronized (internalChannels) {
                final int firstNull = Arrays.asList(internalChannels).indexOf(null);
                internalChannels[firstNull] = ctx.channel();
                internalChannels.notify();
            }
            super.channelActive(ctx);
        }

        @Override
        protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf msg) {
            final ChannelHandlerContext upstreamCtx = Parallelizer.this.upstreamCtx.get();
            msg.retain();
            if (upstreamCtx != null)
                upstreamCtx.writeAndFlush(msg, upstreamCtx.channel().voidPromise());
        }
    }
}
```